# How can i get the class name (as a string) that begins with "test-" using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

question really says it all,

if have an element

```
<span class="a-class another-class test-top-left"></span>
```

how can i get the classname, beginning with "test-" into a string variable so i can then extract the top and left words from that classname into separate variables and use them.

Comment: For a better understanding: You want extract the classname that beginns with 'test' int o a variable from type String?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var test = (​$("span[class*='test-']")[0].className​​).split("test-")​[1].split("-");
```

Where test[0] will contain "top" and test[1] will contain "left".

Here's the working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/kayen/QJCpc/

Comment: this seems to be the simplest solution, but how would this be modified to search only for the class within $(this) ?

Comment: $(this)[0].className.split("test-")​[1].split("-");

Comment: or if you want to go the pure jQuery way: $(this).attr("class").split("test-")​[1].split("-");

Comment: @Jai This solution only works if the class in question is the last or only class on the element. Examples: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/QJCpc/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/QJCpc/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a regex to find and extract the class.  Step-by-step demos here: http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/baVq5/1/ and http://jsfiddle.net/JAAulde/baVq5/2/

```
    /* Get the class attribute from the element */
var wholeclass = $('span').attr('class'),
    /* Define a regex to find the class in question */
    pattern = /(?:^|\s)test-[a-z0-9_-]+(?:\s|$)/mi,
    /* run the regex against the class */
    matches = wholeclass.match(pattern),
    /* get the portion of the match array and trim it up */
    extractedclass = $.trim(matches[0]);
```

Comment: I'd use **$("span[class*='test-']")** as we're specifically looking for elements containing the 'test-*' class only.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed he had code working to find the span in question already, so I focused in on the specifics of extracting a classname from the list.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myClasses = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].className.split(' '),
    Lastclass = myClasses[myClasses.length-1].split('-'),

    first = Lastclass[0],  //test
    second = Lastclass[1], //top
    third = Lastclass[2];  //left
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PbamJ/)

Comment: Note that this approach requires a shim for `classList` support in several browsers, including all versions of IE: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classList

Comment: @JAAulde - Who uses IE anyway :-) -changed it to className, does'nt really matter, it just seemed like something that would be easy to do without jQuery ? Right now it only gets the last class, but with a regex or some creative indexOf it could just as easily find the string "test".