# jquery hasClass, can it be given the beginning of class name, to get the full class name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to do something similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333210/how-can-i-get-the-class-name-as-a-string-that-begins-with-test-using-jquery), but it's a bit different, so the solution there isn't working for me.

```
<span class="a-class another-class test-top-left"></span>
```

I have an element (this code shows a `span` but it could be `div` `span` or anything). This element has a class beginning with `test-` (`test-top-left`, `test-top-right` etc.) I've triggered a click event on classes starting with `test-` and saved the clicked object as `var object = this;`. Simple stuff so far.

What I'm trying to do now is get the full name of that class (`test-top-left`). I know it starts with `test-` but what's the full name. **The thing is that there are other classes `a-class` `another-class` and `test-top-left`.** Can `hasClass` be used to get the full name of the class? I'd prefer not to use `find()` or `filter()` just because there may be additional elements within that also have `class="test-"`

**Edit:**

The code I have now is, but it gives me ALL the classes. What I need is the single class beginning with `test-`.

```
var object = this;
$(object).attr('class');
```

So now I for loop through all the classes and test each one separately, which seems like a lot of unnecessary code. I'm hoping jQuery has a clever way to get the exact class that was clicked right away.

Comment: And what if an element has two classes beginning with `test-`? How will your code know which one you want?

Comment: @Blazemonger That won't be a problem. A single element won't have 2 test classes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Description

You can use jQuerys `Attribute Contains Selector`, `.attr()` and `.click()` method.

> **Attribute Contains Selector** - Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.
>
> **.attr()** -  Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.
>
> **.click()** - Bind an event handler to the "click" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

#### Sample

**html**

```
<span class="anyclass test-hello">Hello World</span>​
```

**jQuery**

```
$("[class*='test']").click(function() {
    var object = $(this);
    alert(object.attr("class").match(/(test-.*?)(?:\s+|$)/)[1])
;});
```

#### Check out the updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyUPq/2/)

### Update

If you dont want to use regex you can do this.

```
$("[class*='test']").click(function() {
    var object = $(this);
    alert("test-" + object.attr("class").split("test-")[1].split("-"))
;});
```

​

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Attribute Contains Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)
- [jQuery - .attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)
- [jQuery - .click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/PyUPq/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the update. So I guess `hasClass` can't be used here? What I was looking for is something like `object.hasClass()` but give hasClass only part of the class name.

Comment: Yes, you cant use hasClass for this. Whats the problem with my answer ? This should do hasClass with starts with.

Answer (score 3):

This should work for you:

```
var object = this;
var className = object.className.match(/(test-.*?)(?:\s+|$)/)[1];
```

Class name is the name of the class you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use split or regex, you can try having the class in a separate attribute

```
<span class="someclass test-something" _rel="test-something">test<span>
```

or

```
<span class="someclass" _rel="test-something">test<span>
```

with the script

```
$("[_rel*='test-']").click(....
```

And to retrieve the attribute, use `$(this).attr("_rel")`