# jQuery having issues with textpath svg elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, toggleclass

I'm using **SVG** in my project and want to **toggleClass** with **jQuery** on the **textpath** elements when clicked.

So I was thinking about:

```
$("text#names > textpath").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("newClass");
});
```

on HTML source:

```
<text id="names" class="clickthrough">
    <textpath class="zoom1" href="#text1" font-size="12.1"></textpath>
    <textpath ... </textpath>
</text>
```

but nothing happens. If I do `$("text#names")` I get the class **clickthrough**. So it is working, just the textpath is maybe not known to jQuery. So I found http://keith-wood.name/svgref.html but before using this, I would like to be sure if it is really needed for my case.

Comment: Basically the same issue as this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8638621/jquery-svg-why-cant-i-addclass

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's `.class` doesn't work with SVG elements, you'll have to use `attr` instead:

```
$("text#names > textpath").click(function() {
  $(this).attr("class", function(_, val){
    return (val.indexOf("newClass")+1) ? val.replace(" newClass","") : val+" newClass";
  });
});
```

Check out [the jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/73m9u1fs/).

Comment: I mean I not even get a result when I have alert("test"); So the main issue is on the click thing.

Comment: @kwoxer Oh, that's odd - mind posting your testing code?

Comment: Sure =) http://jsfiddle.net/kwoxer/5uc17jwr/15/ if you remove > textpath it works. No real clue about this. =/

Comment: @kwoxer been studying it for a while, and I'm baffled; I think it has to be something with the order the elements are being added, because in my example it works fine.

Comment: But how different should I order it. I mean I create some defs and use them afterwards with the fill attribute.

Comment: Okay I think this issue here can be workarounded. Do you know a way to set the click event on all elements that have a class beginning with let's say "event_..."? Nvm: found already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708796/jquery-hasclass-can-it-be-given-the-beginning-of-class-name-to-get-the-full-cl

Comment: Got it working now. The tricky thing was that I have some other elements with the same class. And now hovering a class shall look for similar names class on the SVG. Works now with your code. Big thanks again.

Comment: So, in the end, did you have to use my `.attr` method? Or did it work with `.class`?

Comment: Hey, yeah indeed it just seem to work with .attr. I was not able to get it working with .class.